# Redirecting old sites to new site with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have what I believe is an odd question.

I've designed a new website for a client, and he wants 3 old sites hosted somewhere else to point to his new site.

What his hosting company have done is to change the A records for each of the 3 old sites to point to the IP address of the new site.

They are suggesting that I can have the 3 old url's resolve to the new site by modifying the htaccess file on the new site...

...but I haven't a clue how this would work. I've tried using a 301 redirect (code below) but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help please?

Code I've tried:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.OldSite1\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NewSiteURL.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Just to clarify:

1) the htaccess is on the new site, the hosting company have simply changed the A records of the old sites to point to the IP address of the new site.

2) I have no hosting set up for any of the old sites, so no index.php etc to modify.

3) the redirect will be in the htaccess of the new site, so will need to identify each old url to be redirected to the new URL.

Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If your using apache:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^.*$ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/
```

I'm a little rusty, but I think that's it.
Here is a link to the documentation, may help further:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: What "old domain"? The A record has been changed to the new server. At most it could be a directive in a virtual host block.

Comment: 301 should also be SEO friendly, sorry didn't see the [closed]

Answer (score 1):

Make index.php with

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.newsite.com/');
?>
```

The fastest method ;)

Comment: Of course, this wouldn't work for anything other than the default document on the host.

Comment: Search engines won't like that, a 301 redirect is better.

Comment: Have to agree with that, 301 is much better but as you say, php redirect is very quick and easy but not good for more than development use if SEO is a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Looks right, as long as the path portion of the URLs are the same in the old site and in the new site. I would only add the [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to the rewrite rule. The regular expression is also a bit overkill, you could use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.OldSite1.co.uk [NC]
```

Just make sure that the .htaccess files are being read (i.e. you don't have `AllowOverride None`), or -- better -- put the rewrite rule in the main server config, not in a .htaccess file.